# Create numPy array using list comprehension

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, list-comprehension

Let say I have two numPy arrays `arr1`and `arr2`:

```
arr1 = np.random.randint(3, size = 100)

arr2 = np.random.randint(3, size = 100)
```

I would like to build a matrix that contains the number of joint occurrences. 
In other words, for all the values of `arr1` that are 0, find the elements in `arr2` that are also 0 and are located at the same position. And so, I would like to get the following matrix:

```
M = [[p(0,0), p(0,1), p(0,2)],
     [p(1,0), p(1,1), p(1,2)],
     [p(2,0), p(2,1), p(2,2)]]
```

Where `p(0,0)`stands for the number of occurrences that are 0 on `arr1`and 0 on `arr2`.

**First Attempt:**

As a first attempt I have tried the following:

```
[[sum(arr1[arr2 == y] == x) for x in np.arange(0,3)] for y in np.arange(0,3)]
```

But python throws the following error:

```
NameError: name 'arr1' is not defined
```

**Second Attempt:**

I tried to dig into this error by making use of for-loops:

```
M = np.array([])

for x in np.arange(0,dim):
    result = np.array([])

    for y in np.arange(0,dim):
        result_temp = sum(arr1[arr2 == x] == y)
        result = np.append(result, result_temp)

    M = np.append(M,result)
```

In this case Python does not throw the previous Error, but instead of getting a 3x3 array, I get a 1x9 array, and I am not able to get the desired 3x3 array.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first list comprehension works. You won't get a `NameError` if `arr1` is defined:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(2016)
arr1 = np.random.randint(3, size = 100)
arr2 = np.random.randint(3, size = 100)
result = [[sum(arr1[arr2 == y] == x) for x in np.arange(0,3)] 
          for y in np.arange(0,3)] 
print(result)
# [[10, 9, 10], [8, 13, 15], [18, 8, 9]]
```

But you could instead use [`np.histogram2d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram2d.html):

```
result2, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(arr2, arr1, bins=range(4))
print(result2)
```

yields

```
[[ 10.   9.  10.]
 [  8.  13.  15.]
 [ 18.   8.   9.]]
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer! I am going to use your second solution because although I have defined `arr1`, it still throws the error. I do not understand why.

Answer (score 2):

For performance, I would like to suggest [`np.bincount`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html) -

```
N = 3 # Number of integers to cover
out = np.bincount(arr2*N + arr1, minlength=N*N).reshape(N,N)
```

Sample run -

```
In [50]: arr1 = np.random.randint(3, size = 100)
    ...: arr2 = np.random.randint(3, size = 100)
    ...: 

In [51]: N = 3 # Number of integers to cover

In [52]: np.bincount(arr2*N + arr1, minlength=N*N).reshape(N,N)
Out[52]: 
array([[12, 10, 12],
       [ 7,  6, 20],
       [ 5, 13, 15]])
```